# Error validate an ID token in PHP - Google API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am using the following example [backend-auth Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

```
<?php
    require_once 'Google/vendor/autoload.php';

    $CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    // Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.

    $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    if ($payload) {
        $userid = $payload['sub'];
        // If request specified a G Suite domain:
        //$domain = $payload['hd'];
    } else {
    // Invalid ID token
    }
?>
```

I have already created the credentials, `API`, and `OAUTH2`

```
API_KEY: AIzaAsDfGuYn6nk9761kvnwMxns-PPeO1Ka1YsA
CLIENT_ID: 15123456862-94jrd0d2lis29lbl6dekpk0fp4otgm8r.apps.googleusercontent.com
CLIENT_SECRET: qertf3l3UfgdhjiWEREZI8xN
```

But it generates the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id_token in C:\Adsense\index.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: id_token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken in C:\Adsense\Google\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php:784 Stack trace: #0 C:\Adsense\index.php(10): Google\Client->verifyIdToken(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Adsense\Google\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php on line 784
```

I have searched this forum in the google documentation and in the google console panel but I cannot find a fixed token or how to create it, I cannot find references

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an old post, but for anyone like me and the OP struggling with this, it's actually quite a simple solution.
The example code has a commented out line that reads

```
    // Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.
```

You actually have to write this code. Using the worked examples from Google, the JavaScript function passes the authentication token as idtoken.

```
    $id_token = $_POST['idtoken'];
```

Will do the trick. You'll probably want to perform some basic error checking, for example,

```
    if (isset($_POST['idtoken'])){
        $id_token = $_POST['idtoken'];
        $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);

        ...
```